# Strange Build Message from Linux Kernel

Tags: build-process, makefile, linux-kernel

I was trying to rebuild my kernel after modifying some source files and noticed the following message in the build output:

> II: New modules (you've been busy, wipe the poop off your nose)

What is that supposed to mean?

What other weirdness awaits me in the Kernel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error is produced by a module checking script that is part of the kernel build process for Ubuntu. There is actually [a bug filed about its inappropriateness](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-meta/+bug/316208).

The script checks to see if there are any missing modules from this build compared to previous builds. It is used to catch configuration settings that inadvertently result in any modules not being built ([see this post](http://www.linux-archive.org/ubuntu-kernel-team/247883-ubuntu-build-cpu-frequency-scaling-drivers.html)).

Your message is an informative one and not an error. It simply means that there have been new modules compiled in this build and should not require any action on your part.

Incidentally, if you're interested in looking at other inappropriate language in the Linux kernel, [check out these graphs](http://www.vidarholen.net/contents/wordcount/).

Answer (score 0):

It's been logged as a bug in Ubuntu:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/316208